# C# 2DGraphics.Transform

Tags: c#, 2d

hope anyone can help with this question even my english is poor. Im drawing lets say a square on the screen with a Graphics that has a transform and that works just fine but the user should be allowed to click on a point inside that square and i need to know the point as if the square was drawn without an transform. I need with other words to know what square the user clicked. Hope some understand what i mean. Thanks!

Maybee this help to understand the problem

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.RotateAt(rot, new PointF(imgrect.Left + imgrect.Width / 2, imgrect.Top + imgrect.Height / 2));
Graphics.Transform = m;
Graphics.DrawImage(img, imgrect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring the mouse coordinate into the rectangle's object space

```
bool RotatedRectContains(Rectangle rect, Matrix transform, Point mousePos)
{
  Point[] pts = { mousePos };
  Matrix inverseMat = transform.Clone();
  inverseMat.Inverse();
  inverseMat.TransformPoints(pts);

  return rect.Contains(pts[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ups... i found the solution myself if we say the user clicked a point p the convertation will be:
`Point[] pts = new Point[1];`
`pts[0] = p;`
`m.Invert();`
`m.VectorTransformPoints(pts);`
`pts[0].X += (int)m.OffsetX;`
`pts[0].Y += (int)m.OffsetY;`

Now pts[0] can be used to find the square that was clicked,